# Define rules for casting to custom datatypes in C

Tags: c, struct, types, casting, user-defined-data-types

For the built-in datatypes (e.g. `int`, `float` etc), there are built-in 'rules' for casting: e.g.

```
int x, float y;
x = 3;
y = x;
```

will produce `y = 3.000000`.

Is there any way to define custom 'casting rules' for my own datatypes defined by typedefs?

Say I have a struct `rational` representing a rational number. I would like to be able to cast `int` variables to `rational` such that the denominator field is set to `1` and the numerator is equal to the initial `int`. I.e. if I do:

```
typedef struct rational{int num; int denom;} rational;
int x, rational y;
x = 3;
y = x;
```

I want to get `y.num = 3` and `y.denom = 1`.

Can arbitrary functions be defined to control the behaviour when casting to/from user-defined datatypes?

Failing that, is it possible to set a 'default' value for a subset of a struct's members (such that that member can be optionally skipped when assigning a value to a variable of that type, defaulting to the set value)?

Comment: No, not in C language. In C++ you can  overload the `=` operator defining own method

Comment: Note that a cast is an explicit operator in C. `y = (float) x;` has a cast. `y = x;` does not have a cast. It has a conversion, and the conversion is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C++ which allows you to overload the typecast operator and assignment operator, C doesn't allow you to define your own casts or implicit conversions.

You'll need to write a function that performs the conversion.  For example:

```
rational int_to_rational(int x)
{
    rational r = { x, 1 };
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> For the built-in datatypes (e.g. `int`, `float` etc), there are built-in 'rules' for casting

No, there are not.  "Casting" is the effect of typecast operator, which is a type *conversion*.  There are some conversions that are performed without casting, but no casts are performed without a cast operator.

> Is there any way to define custom 'casting rules' for my own datatypes defined by typedefs

Typedefs are just aliases for types.  They have nothing to do with defining a new type.

If you create a `typedef` alias for a type that affords automatic conversions then those will apply equally to objects and values whose type is described via the `typedef`.  But as far as the language spec goes, there are automatic conversions only where the spec says there are.  Some C implementations extend that set -- for example, to provide automatic conversions between integers and pointers -- but **no C implementation I know allows the code being compiled to define new automatic conversions**.  C++ is over yonder.